# Parabolas with axis parallel to the x-axis on pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, overleaf

Good morning,

I've benn learning using LaTeX since a few week and I'm actually learning how to use **pgfplots** to create graphs of function 'cause as a scientific student, it helps me a lot.

I can create graph of functions like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [ylabel = $y$, xlabel = $x$,
        ymin = -10, ymax = 10,
        xmin = -5, xmax =5,
        axis lines = middle,
        width = 8cm, height = 8cm]

        \addplot[domain = -10:10, samples = 100, blue] {x^2};

        \addplot[domain = -10:10, red]{2*x+5};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In theese days I need to cerate graphs of parabolas with axis parallel with the x-axis and i don't know how can I make it (I don't know if it possible also).

So, does a way to create this type of graph exist?

I use **Overleaf** as a compiler.

PS: I would like to create a graph of a function like this: *y = sqrt(4-x)*.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. // A way to do it is plotting two functions: y1=sqrt(4-x) and y2=-y1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [kind of parametric plot](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-addplot#sec-14.3). The normal `\addplot {f(x)}` is the same as `\addplot (x, {f(x)})`, but you can swap x and y:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [ylabel = $y$, xlabel = $x$,
        ymin = -10, ymax = 10,
        domain = -10:10,
        xmin = -5, xmax =5,
        axis lines = middle,
        width = 8cm, height = 8cm]

        \addplot[samples = 100, blue] {x^2};
        \addplot[red]{2*x+5};
        \addplot[thick, domain=-5:5, variable=t]  ({t^2/10}, t);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: two parabolas and a line]

Here I used `t` to avoid confusion... what the instruction does, is to run `t` through the domain specified (in this case, -5 to 5) using the specified number of samples; the it plots the `(x, y)` point with the calculation you specify. Try, for fun,

```
\addplot[purple, samples=100, domain=-180:180, variable=t]  ({5*sin(2*t}, {5*cos(6*t)});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

But, i didn't understand how this newvariable actually works....
Could you explain it?

Comment: @LorenzoLettieri, you just calculate x(t) and y(t). Think of varying y=y(t)=t instead of x in your mind, i.e. interchange roles of x and y. No rocket science ;-)

Comment: Thank you! It works!!!